# Why is this derivation of Schmitt trigger circuit's output signal, incorrect?

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger, positive-feedback

[image]

This is the reference Schmitt trigger circuit. Using KVL, \$V_x\$ turns out to be \$\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_o\$. Also,

$$V_o = A\left( V_x - V_i\right)$$
$$V_o = A\left( \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_o - V_i\right)$$
$$\left( \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - {1\over A}\right)V_o = V_i$$
$$V_o = \frac{V_i}{\left( \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} - {1\over A}\right)}$$

Since A is a very large number, \$\frac{1}{A} \to 0\$

$$V_o = \frac{V_i}{\left( \frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\right)} = \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1}V_i$$

If \$R_1=R_2=1k\Omega, A=2\times 10^5, V_i=2\sin\left( \omega t\right) V, V_{cc}=3V\text{ and }V_{EE}=3V\$, then the graph would look like this (according to the above formulation),

[image]
*A rough representation of input and output signals*

In reality the output signal is completely different. I know how OP-Amp with positive feedback work. But I am just curious as to why the above derivation is incorrect. Particularly which step.

Comment: The circuit has *hysteresis*. It shouldn't be possible to write \$V_o\$ as a *function* of \$V_i\$ *alone*, since functions don't have *memory* while hysteresis does. Also \$V_o\$ undergoes saturation which doesn't seem to be modelled in your equations. Output voltage saturation is important to the working of this circuit.

Comment: @AJN Still, even without saturation the correct equations should have an output sine wave thousands upon thousands of times larger than the input. How do you account for memory without needing to know the circuit has hysteresis to begin with? You almost need to add initial conditions or something for Vx and Vout, but you normally wouldn't do that unless you knew it was important ahead of time.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have *attempted* an answer below. You are right about knowing the system has memory before attempting to solve the system algebraically. That is why I want the saturation non linearity also to be modelled which will prevent the simplification OP has done after the second step.

Comment: Assume that your opamp output is at positive saturation +3V next find the voltage at the Vx node and is if Vin = Vx it will be your threshold voltage. Next, assume a negative situation -3V and find Vx. And you will have your threshold voltage  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465430/waveform-at-the-negative-terminal-of-an-opamp/465585#465585

Comment: This is basically a sine to square wave converter. It cannot compete with logic based Schmitt triggers in terms of speed or clean rising / falling edges. Normally logic gates never go below zero volts. This only makes sense in the analog domain.

Comment: Also, a *real* op amp (in contrast to the ideal op amp assumed here) may not work for this purpose (as a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator#Op-amp_voltage_comparator)), e.g. due to [phase reversal](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-036.pdf). The older TL084 certainly does not.

Comment: _But I am just curious as to why the above derivation is incorrect. Particularly which step._  I could be awfully wrong, but I think it is here:  **Vo = A(Vx - Vi)**.  You assume A is finite, and derive other equations from that, then at the end you say, no, it's really infinite.  It reminds me (can't find it now) of the derivation that 1 equals 2 when starting from 1 + 1 = 2. Again, I could be quite wrong. Good question!

Comment: the golden rules of op amps only apply when there is negative feedback, which is lacking in this circuit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Point 1

The Schmitt trigger has hysteresis. Hysteresis implies that the circuit has *memory*. It remembers it last state. For a system with memory, you cannot write \$V_o = f(V_{in})\$. It should be of the format \$V_o = f(V_{in}, V_{o, \text{prev}})\$ or something equivalent.<sub>As one of the comments mentioned below the question indicates, one would not know the system has memory the first time they try to solve the circuit using equations. IMHO, In that case, the following section would safeguard against an erroneous conclusion.</sub>

### Point 2

Output voltage being able to saturate is also an important feature since it prevents \$V_o\$ and \$V_x\$ reinforcing each other to infinity. Your equations do not model the saturation non-linearity.

Your second equation would have been better written as

\$
V_o = \min(\max(A(f(V_o) - V_{in}), -V_{max}), V_{max})
\$

With this scaffolding to represent the non-linearity, all further simplification attempted in the question would have been prevented.

### edit

<sub>In response to OP's question below in comments.</sub>

Let's analyse the **case where** \$V_{in} = 0\$. OP's second equation simplifies to

\$V_o = A(\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}V_o - 0)\$.

Neglecting the saturation, and for \$A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} > 1\$, the solution to this system is

\$V_o = 0\$ or \$V_o = \infty\$
(since \$0 = A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} \cdot 0\$ and
\$\infty = A\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2} \cdot \infty\$).

This means that, if the opamp output is forced to 0 and if there is no noise (or any other imperfection) in the system, the output remains there (OP's waveform also show zero volt output for zero volt input).

In a practical circuit, the output will be displaced from 0 volts by noise. So the question is, will the system remain there? Will the system move back to zero volt or \$\infty\$ volts? Dynamics (time evolution) of the system is not modelled by OP's equations, so, we cannot answer this question keeping ourselves to the algebraic equations where time is *not* modelled. If time was also modelled, *I think* we could have concluded that the 0 volt equilibrium point is unstable and the \$\infty\$ volt equilibrium (or \$V_{max}\$) is stable and system will have tendency to move towards the extreme output situation.

In short, using the algebraic equation above, we cannot analyse the this circuit when the output is not touching the saturation values (\$-V_{max} < V_o < V_{max}\$) since a practical system will have tendency to shift towards the saturation points and not lie exactly on the solution to the algebraic equation above.

### edit 2

<sub>In response to comments below which ask to forget hysteresis stuff. I am attempting to construct an example without hysteresis</sub>

Let me try to make a point with an analogy where an algebraic solution exists, but output is unbounded. This analogous system also has positive feedback. It too has finite output predicted by the equation. But output is unbounded.

[image: positive feedback]

The output-input relation is given by

\$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} ={}& x(t) \color{red}{+} y(t)\\
(s-1)Y(s) ={}& X(s)\\
\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} ={}& \frac{1}{s-1}
\end{align}
\$

For any finite amplitude sinusoid signal (including 0 frequency), the output predicted by the transfer function is finite. But the system will have unbounded output. The **gain** of this system as a function of frequency is same as the system \$\frac{1}{s+1}\$. I think this example forms a nice parallel to your example. No hysteresis or saturation was used in this example.

Comment: Yeah, it is really weird how OP's derivation somehow made the open-loop gain disappear when we know just from examination of the feedback that it doesn't disappear. But I don't know what to do about it since if you just stare at the math it looks fine. The fundamental approach is wrong I guess.

Comment: The fundamental problem may lie in trying to analyse this as a linear circuit with fixed gain which allows output to go to any level, while in reality, the output is clamped to some level. I think OP's troubles started between second and third line when they took the \$V_o\$ term in RHS to LHS. With the non linearity modelled, the \$\max\$, \$\min\$ functions would have stopped the derivation there.

Comment: Yeah. It's a nonlinear circuit being analyzed using linear methods. That sort of just leads back to how do you know its a non-linear circuit to begin with. Then again, non-linear has always been something that you have to walk into with both eyes open. The only rule is that there are no rules.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that A is not important, but V_sat is what is important. final hysteresis is also a function of V_sat, right ? But OP has not modelled it anywhere in the derivation.

Comment: I agree that we have to know before hand that this circuit will send the opamp into non linear region of operation.

Comment: Is this a circuit that undergrads are expected to be able to analyze? Because it certainly *looks* like one at first glance.

Comment: If they are not given clues about the positive feedback and the hysteresis, they might not be (I definitely wouldn't have). But I think this type of circuit is common enough that it is usually a part of the syllabus where opamp circuits are taught.

Comment: @AJN Great answer, but I have another doubt now. I agree, not considering V_sat in my equations was a flaw. But this equation does consider it.

 $$V_o = \min(\max(A(f(V_o) - V_{in}), -V_{max}), V{max})$$

Let's assume \$-V_{max}<A(f(V_o) - V_{in})<V_{max}\$, therefore \$V_o = A(f(V_o) - V_{in})\$.  Now further calculation would result in the same answer which I got using above derivation. And the above assumption will be true if \$V_{max} > \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1}V_i\$. Is this correct?

Comment: @AkashKarnatak I have made an edit in the answer, which may answer the above comment. IMO, for this circuit, the model of the system with the linear algebraic equations, without including time variable, is not sufficient to capture the behaviour of the actual circuit. Since this circuit can be simulated in SPICE, we know for certain that a model involving saturation, time dependence, etc can duplicate the behaviour of this circuit.

Comment: This accepted does not answer the fundamental question if I may say... **why is it just a clipped sine wave output** Forget the hysteresis stuff.  This a bad assumption on the Op Amp not be a suitable high speed comparator due Av(f)= 2e5/f for f>10Hz for f=0.35/ rise time 10~90%

Comment: I deleted my misunderstood answer too

Comment: @AkashKarnatak consider **un**marking this answer as accepted if it doesn't fully explain your question. There are competing answers now with more votes.

Comment: @AJN I accepted this answer as it pointed out why my derivation was incorrect. As of now there are many good answers but I can barely understand what they have written. I am just beginning with OP-Amps so I don't know which answer to mark as correct. If you can tell me which answer may better help future readers, I'll mark that as correct.

Comment: With my last edit, my answer has come around to what is posted by user287001. You can go trough the other answers once more and reconsider. only a suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

You made an assumption there's a stable output and calculated what the output should be in case the assumption is right. In addition you clipped the result to the possible output voltage range. The clipping is ok, but the assumption of the existence of stable output is not, as persons who know the feedback stability theory could confirm (see NOTE1)

People make same kind of reasoning continuously. Actually the whole physics is based on this kind of reasoning. There comparing to measurements is the way to reveal wrong assumptions.

NOTE1: there's no need to be an academic level mathematician or engineer to be able to make it clear a stable output can be achieved only because the limited voltage range clips the output. Some elementary Laplace domain analysis is enough.

If we assume there's some realistic slowness in the amp, say one RC charging and the gain is finite, maybe big, but finite we can find the transfer function for the whole circuit. Th slowness prevents infinitely fast changes so we can follow what the circuit does.

We can replace the ideal amplification A with G/(1+sRC) which is the transfer function of buffered RC integrator. G is the DC gain of the amp.

Let's also simplify the formula by replacing R1/(R1+R2) with a single symbol B. It's our feedback attenuation factor which is between 0 and 1.

The s-domain gain of the system is Vo/Vi = 1/(B-(1+sRC)/G)

Of course the output stays zero if the input is zero and there's no noise. But there's always some noise. We can find which s-domain frequencies start to ring in the system from the slightest pulse of noise by calculating which values of s make the denominator infinite (=find the poles of the transfer function). We solve s from equation (B-(1+sRC)/G)=0

The result is s=(GB-1)/RC

The Laplace transformation math says that the output from a slightest pulse of noise is proportional to an exponential voltage exp(t/T) with time constant T=RC/(GB-1). This T is positive as soon as GB is bigger than 1. Positive time constant means limitless grow which is in practice stopped only by the limited output voltage range. Negative T (i.e. GB <1) means that the ringing in the loop decays and the output stabilizes to the value which can be calculated with your original formula for Vo. But for a stable output A must be less than how much the feedback voltage divider attenuates.

Answer (score 0):

### Circuit with hysteresis

First, I will comment on the memory properties of this circuit with hysteresis. Yes, it has memory... and it can act both as a *Schmitt trigger* and an *RS latch*.

**Schmitt trigger.** In these applications, the input voltage smoothly varies in both directions. The circuit behaves as a latch forced by the input voltage to stay in one of its two states. We take advantage of the *sharp transitions* and *hysteresis* to reduce various interferences.

**Latch.** In these applications, we toggle the circuit with hysteresis in one state or another by bipolar pulses (by changing for a moment the input voltage above/below the positive/negative threshold and then returning it to zero). The input voltage has three levels: Vin > +Vth (R), Vin < -Vth (S) and Vin = 0 (neutral). To make this latch behave again as a trigger, do not return to zero. This idea can be implemented by connecting the inverting input through a resistor to ground. The latch can be toggled by touching for a moment the input to VCC or -VEE .

More generally speaking, we can control a circuit with hysteresis in two different ways - by changing the input signal out of the hysteresis loop "without returning" (Schmitt trigger) and "with returning" (latch) it inside the loop (usually, in the middle).

### RS latch

Then let's see if we can convert a latch into a Schmitt trigger.

**RS latch with 2-input logic gates.** The problem of this implementation is in its *one-way inputs*. The output voltage of the positive feedback and the input voltage are connected by a logic function (NAND or NOR) but not by an arithmetic function (summing) as in the case of the Schmitt trigger. That is why, once we toggle the latch through some of its inputs, we cannot toggle it back by the same input (it has lost its controlling function); we can do it by the other input.

**RS latch with 1-input logic gates.** There is no such a problem if the latch is implemented by 1-input gates (inverters) since they have *2-way inputs*. A typical example is the RAM cell whose inputs/outputs can be controlled in both directions.

---

As a conclusion, it seems we can talk about the use of hysteresis only in devices with one input (Schmitt trigger or a 1-input latch).

Comment: I don't have time to explain why equating a latch and a Schmitt trigger is an invalid statement, but I will tell you that's why I downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the frankness... It would be interesting to see what you think since I am absolutely sure they are the same devices with hysteresis. Only the ways they are controlled are different - by one input with two different polarities (Schmitt trigger) or by two inputs with the same polarity (RS latch). These are my favorite experiments conducted with my students - to convert a Schmitt trigger into a latch and an RS latch into a Schmitt trigger. I think I have movies from the DC laboratory; if I find them, I will place links here.

Comment: Here is a "magnetic RS latch" implemented on the base of a "magnetic Schmitt trigger"- https://photos.app.goo.gl/mDM4k3HaYuDCa2DL2. The idea is the same as in the electronic implementation. Can you guess what is inside the box? If not, I will place a link to another movie that reveals the secret...

Comment: Your language is confusing and contradictory, If "Schmitt trigger is a latch" then it doesn't make sense to ask a student to "convert a Schmitt trigger into a latch". If a "latch is a Schmitt trigger" then it doesn't make sense to talk about a "latch **implemented on the base of** a...Schmitt trigger".

Comment: @ElliotAlderson we know they are functionally the same , but as the bipolar latching relay , but not dual line latching magnetic relay , so @ CF it’s not all Latches and not all Schmitt Triggers use GND for a Ref.if the output is unipolar.

Comment: @ Elliot Alderson, Confusing is that I open your eyes to see the truth about these genius circuits from the last century... but instead to thank me, you downvote my answer. There is only one device - a "circuit with hysteresis"... but we can controll it in two different ways - by changing the input signal out of the hysteresis loop "without returning" (Schmitt trigger) and "with returning" (latch) it inside the loop (usually, in the middle). Here is how, in the early 80's, I converted a "magnetic Schmitt trigger" into a "magnetic latch" - https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pgw33DNwwnmmy3pE8 ...

Comment: ... I deliberately hid this little "device" (the battery, resistor and LED are auxiliary) in a big box to make a joke with sages like you by making them synthesize the supposed circuit inside. It was very interesting because they were making all sorts of complicated circuits... and they were very surprised to see what was inside. BTW I got a patent for such a device used in alarm systems ...

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75, I'm not sure if I understand the meaning of your comment correctly... but if you are talking about the "neutral level" of the input signal when the latch is in a stand-by (memoryzing) mode, it has to be chosen inside (usually, in the middle of) the hysteresis curve. It will be zero, if the circuit is bipolar and its hysteresis curve is symmetrical. In the case of the reed switch in the movie, it is moved (biased) to the right. I hope you share my insights about the connection betwen the legendary 1918's Eccles&Jordan latch and the famous 1934's Schmitt trigger.

Comment: The magnetic latch or relay analogy is good for a Schmitt Trigger. being there are two types of magnetic latching relays bipolar with only the 1 wire latching relay that matches using electronic hysteretic switch. with Normally open bipolar pulses about the floating midpoint bias, with pulse up or down then open to Vout/2 bias. Then they are the same. But not for DC control as magnetic latches are high coil current and DC could burn them out.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75, The pulse control is energy saving since the relay acting as a latch does not consume current like the magnetic-core memory from the past; it is a volatile memory switch...
But it seems that I should refine my point of view on hysteresis. Maybe we should talk about the use of hysteresis only in devices with one input (Schmitt trigger or a 1-input latch). In the classic 2-input RS latch the hysteresis can be also observed in each input... but it is not used (like in 555 timer)...

Comment: It not energy saving alone but DC will overheat it. I understand how they work, rather I was trying explain the differences.

Comment: @Tony, We can say that the pulse-controlled coil resembles a CMOS latch that consumes a current only during the transition. I think I also understand how they work but, in addition, I try to explain the differences between them...

Comment: OK, I will share some final remarks and then will add all this wisdom to my answer. The problem of the RS latch when implemented by 2-input logic gates are its one-way inputs. The output voltage of the positive feedback and the input voltage are connected by a logic function (AND or NOR) but not by an arithmetic function (summing). That is why, once we toggled the latch through some of its inputs, we cannot toggle it back by the same input (it has lost its controlling function); we can do it by the other input.There is no such a problem if the latch is implemented by 1-input gates (inverters).

Comment: It’s just that your equivalent that all Hysteric comparators are equivalent to all relay latches non-volatile, only the bipolar single coil types. Even though that is stretching it by me saying it can be bipolar about Vdd/2 or with an offset  which was unfortunately missing in this OP’s example.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it look like an amplified clipped sine wave for Hysteric comparator using an Op Amp?

The GBW limits in Op Amps make poor high speed comparators since open loop they are just integrators with a LPF breakpoint near 10Hz or so.

Rise time is normally limited by output current into std load of 30pF.  But in this case rise time is limited by internal compensation cap. So

If DC gain is Av=2e5 and GBW=4e5 then AC gain is only.
**Av(f)<~2** estimated by your waves

So rise time , Tr is measure by 10~90% and f by -3dB point so f=0.35 You get **Tr= 0.35 / f @-3dB**

Just like your output.

All the hysteresis is correct.

Meanwhile positive feedback works as expected.

Suggestion

- use a logic gate or open collector comparator with 1k pullup and Rf=100k And Rin is the ratio if hysteresis. Then expect fast fall times but slow rise with xx pF loads.
- use a CMOS Schmitt trigger designed for 1/3 hysteresis