# Why does output become inverted in op-amp astable multivibrator?

Tags: amplifier, multivibrator, astable

[image]

This is the circuit I'm considering.

I understand how V<sub>o</sub> becomes V<sub>sat</sub>, and V<sub>n</sub> increases until it is equal to V<sub>p</sub>, which is R1/(R1+R2)·V<sub>sat</sub>.

Many people say when V<sub>n</sub> slightly exceeds V<sub>p</sub>, V<sub>o</sub> is inverted.

However, my question is: how can V<sub>n</sub> exceed V<sub>p</sub>?

Right after V<sub>n</sub> becomes equal to V<sub>p</sub>, the output V<sub>o</sub> will become zero (by comparator). Then C will discharge, then V<sub>n</sub> < V<sub>p</sub>, V<sub>o</sub> becomes +V<sub>sat</sub> again, and V<sub>n</sub> increases again until it becomes equal to V<sub>p</sub> and V<sub>o</sub> will be zero again, therefore V<sub>o</sub> will be oscillating between zero and V<sub>sat</sub>.

Is this wrong?

Comment: You are asking about positive feedback action in this circuit? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465430/waveform-at-the-negative-terminal-of-an-opamp/465585#465585

Comment: I'm mainly asking why the output doesn't become zero when Vref=Vin.

Comment: Due to positive feedback provided by R2, R1 voltage divider

Comment: Then Vout is nonzero even if Vp=Vn? Due to what principle?

Comment: Do you understand that there are 2 trip points ?

Comment: If you use bipolar supply.

Comment: We have an opamp output at +Vsat and the capacitor voltage is rising (Vn < VP). And when Vn = Vp the opamp output voltage starts to decrease towards -Vsat. But, notice that the capacitor voltage continues to rise (because of Vn < +Vsat). Also, as output voltage "moves" towards -Vsat the Vp will start to decrease along with Vout. Thus, we no longer have Vn = Vp but we have  Vn < Vp instead. And this process cannot be stopped because Vp follows Vout the changes due to positive feedback provided by R2, R1 voltage divider.  Do you see it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the amplifier/comparator to have a bipolar supply.

Then the output will saturate at Vsat+/Vsat- depending on the polarity of the input.

You are correct that this circuit will not work properly as shown with a single positive supply. Additional biasing can make it work with a single supply (a single resistor from Vp to the positive rail).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know that there are negative saturation voltage when bipolar power is supplied. My main curiosity is how can output be inverted from positive Vsat to negative Vsat. Like I demostrated above.

Comment: The ideal behavior of the amplifier is that Vout = Vsat+ when Vp>Vn, Vout = Vsat- when Vp < Vn. By definition.

Comment: How about Vp=Vn?

Comment: @user18926955 we don't talk about Vp = Vn.

Comment: More seriously, if you introduce something like Vout = 0 for Vp=Vn you introduce a mathematical (not real) possibility of the circuit not oscillating because it is sitting in an unstable state with Vout = 0. Real circuits will transition over a narrow and somewhat unstable tiny change of voltage near 0V (maybe within +/-1mV or less, depending on the part) and the gain will be very large so a few uV might change the output. So it's better to consider Vout is always Vsat+ or Vsat- (put an  >= or <= in there if it makes you feel better).

Comment: The unstable state can't persist in reality because of the positive feedback and noise/drift. Once the oscillator starts going it's even more sure.

Comment: I'm truely impressed for your detailed answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All this can be view when making the simulations.
Ever check your "thinking" ...
As pointed out by @Spehro Pefhany ...

When bipolar supplies ... with 2 trip points.

[image]

With unipolar supply ... Where is the other?

[image]

With an added resistor to the ground ...
Note that the R6 value is very "special" ... to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you've assumed that the negative power supply potential to the op-amp is 0V. This circuit can only work when the negative supply potential to the op-amp is, well, negative. In other words, you need a dual supply, such as +12V and -12V for this circuit to work.

If the op-amp's negative supply potential is 0V, the lowest output you can have from the op-amp is zero volts, which has the following consequences:

- When the op-amp output *is* zero volts (\$V_O = 0\$), the potential divider formed by R1 and R2 present 0V to the non-inverting input, so \$V_P = 0\$
- When the op-amp output *is* zero volts (\$V_O = 0\$), the inverting input (derived from C and Rf) can *never* fall below 0V either. Therefore the inverting input cannot ever fall below the inverting input in potential. Always \$V_N \ge V_P\$

In other words, you seem to have identified a potential problem (pun completely intended). Once the output falls low (0V), the circuit is stuck in that state.

The only way this circuit can oscillate is if the op-amp's output is permitted to become negative, and the only way that can happen is if the op-amp's negative supply potential is negative.

#### Edit

It's possible to modify this circuit to operate from a single-ended supply, by biasing the op-amp's feedback potentials. The idea is to raise the two switching threshold potentials so that they sit above and below half of the supply voltage. The lower threshold is then well above zero, allowing the the junction of C and Rf to swing below it, something that it can't do in the existing setup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYTmwV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here R1 and R2 have changed role. They now provide a potential half way between the supplies, at +2.5V. R3 allows the op-amp output to modulate that value somewhat. The simplest way to understand this is by replacing the combination of the +5V source, R1 and R2 (boxed in blue) with their Thévenin equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjMpu2.png)</sup>

Now it becomes clear that as the output switches between +5V and 0V, the potential divider formed by Rth and R3 applies feedback with some fraction of the amplitude of that oscillation (one half in this example, since Rth = R3), centered about +2.5V.

With the values shown, and assuming the op-amp output is rail-to-rail, the two threshold values will be \$V_P = +2.5 \pm \frac{2.5}{2}\$, or \$V_P = 3.75, 1.25\$