# How do the comparators in this circuit work? Do they compare the voltages between themselves? How do comparators generally work?

Tags: schematics, windturbine

[image]
This is the schematic of the circuit my question references. I understand that the potentiometers are set at 2 different levels and the comparators then send out signals based on whether its above or below the charge levels, but I'm wondering exactly how they know?

Comment: Takee a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465430/waveform-at-the-negative-terminal-of-an-opamp/465585#465585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two 3.3K resistors form a fixed voltage divider across the battery, producing half the battery voltage.

Meanwhile, the LM7808 provices a constant 8V, that won't change (unless the battery is really flat).  This is then divided down using two more voltage dividers in the form of 10K potentiometers.  But each comparator has its own potentiometer, and they can be adjusted differently.

A comparator compares its + and - inputs.  If the + input is at a higher voltage than the -, then the comparator output goes high.  If the - input is at a higher voltage than the +, then the output goes low.  Notice how the two comparators' inputs are wired opposite ways round.

The comparators don't talk to each other, but they do both feed into the SR latch formed by IC2a and IC2b.

If you set the 10K potentiometers correctly, one comparator signals when the battery voltage is getting too high, and needs to stop charging.  the other signals when it is too low and needs to start charging.

Answer (score 0):

The two comparators measure the voltage in 3k3 -s middle point and comparators output gets active if one of voltage boundary is found performing the change of NOR latch state.

If no boundery is found the NOR latch holds the last active comparator state.

The buttons are able to change latch state only when no boundery is found ( in comparators inactive zone).